# div goes below parent div (css)

Tags: css, html

So, one more question.

How come that div with phone# image goes below parent div? I tried clear. Didn't help. I tried absolute positioning parent "pics", but it threw everything to the left.
[See here](http://mannshinyhomes.com/)

```
<div id="angies"></div>
<div id="est"></div>
<div id="pics">
<div id="logot"></div>
<div id="house"></div>
<div id="phone"></div>
</div>

#angies {height:124px;
width:347px;
margin-right:0px;
margin-top:0px;
float:right;
background-image: url(images/ang.jpg);
background-repeat:no-repeat;}

#est {height:16px;
width:165px;
margin-left:5px;
    margin-top:5px;
background-image: url(images/est.jpg);
background-repeat: no-repeat;}

#pics {height:175px;
width:878px;
border:1px solid;
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;}

#logot {height:169px;
width:360px;
border:1px solid;
float:left;
margin-bottom:0px;
background-image:url(images/logot.jpg);
background-repeat:no-repeat;}

#house {height:169px;
width:166px;
border:1px solid;
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;
margin-bottom:0px;
background-image:url(images/house.jpg);
background-repeat:no-repeat;}

#phone {height:43px;
width:312px;
border:1px solid;
position:relative;
margin-bottom:0px;
margin-left:526px;
position:static;
background-image:url(images/phone.jpg);
background-repeat:no-repeat;}
```

p.s.
and how come these divs are going to the top with bottom margin of 0 pixels? It doesn't bother me this very moment, but i still want to know how come.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

simple solution is make all of them float: left

```
#house { float: left; }
#phone { float: left; }
```

Comment: it did help to get the initial div into parent one. Thank you! But how come `margin-bottom:0px;` doesn't land all three of them on the bottom of parent div?

Comment: margin-bottom only gives the margin space at the bottom, it does not move to the bottom. I think what you after is bottom : 0px; but this does not work with float: left;  Other solution, you can remove the float: left; and implement display: inline-block; instead

Comment: it sends div to the left, right below the logo. And `bottom:0px;` still doesn't get it down

Comment: Never mind. Floated everything left and finished with margin-top. Thanks for help!

Comment: if you want them to stay at the bottom, you can do two way. use display: inline-block; instead of float:left; or in the #phone, create another wrapper. if you can put your code to http://jsfiddle.net/ i can fix it up for you